# Is it possible to sort elasticsearch query by whether or not the field meets the condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got elasticsearch document with mapping like this.

```
{
    "date_added": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
    }
    "expires": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is query with double sort:

1) newest to oldest (that's an easy sort, no problem here)

2) show documents yet to expire on top (so documents where "expires" is greater than now)

In my response I want to get documents sorted in somewhat two parts - yet to expire newest to oldest, expired newest to oldest.

I struggle to create sort that would achieve the second part. Can I sort by result of range filter? Maybe I can create some property-like boolean field that will change depending on "expires" field and later use it for sort?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an excellent use case for function score. You can mention a function score function to increase boost for documents having expiry date larger than now.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "expires": {
                "gte": "now"
              }
            }
          },
          "boost": 1000
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and [here](http://blog.qbox.io/optimizing-search-results-in-elasticsearch-with-scoring-and-boosting).

Comment: That's pretty neat. One thing I worry about is how it will affect overall scoring of my search (example given is quite simplified). I am going to read provided links and check how it works.
How do I sort it at the end though? Won't score sort mess with date_sort (as scores may vary between results)?

Comment: This wont work with sort. Sort will over ride the score and sort on itself. If you want to sort based on a secondary field , you can give one more function there.